# Execution failed for task ':video_player:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors

I am trying to run my flutter project but I can't. I receiving the following error from the console:

```
Execution failed for task ':video_player:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed;
```

I have tried different versions of the `video_player` package but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your android studio.
make sure that you have updated everything in android studio.